# jQuery Datepicker close datepicker after selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hero-unit">
    <input type="text" placeholder="click to show datepicker" id="example1">
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example1').datepicker({
      format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    });
  });
</script>
```

I use bootstrap datepicker.

When I click to datepicker it opens and I select any date.

**My question:**

> If I choose date from datepicker, I want to close datepicker popup.

Which event do i need to use in order to close datepicker on select date?

**Edited:**

**I have found a solution**

This works

```
 $(document).mouseup(function (e) {

        $('#example1').Close();

    });
```

But this **below** does not work why ?

```
 $('#example1').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {

        $('#example1').Close();

    });
```

Comment: $('#example1').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {

        $('#example1').Close();

    }); does not work why any help please

Comment: you don't have to replace all that stuff... just see my post ^^

Comment: Well, your solution is a very good solution , but if you want to use many datepicker components, you need to add a function per input and of course modify the html.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Actually you don't need to replace this all (@Ben Rhouma Zied answere)....

There are 2 ways to do this. One is to use autoclose property, the other (alternativ) way is to use the on change property thats fired by the input when selecting a Date.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hero-unit">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Sample 1: Click to show datepicker" id="example1">
    </div>
    <div class="hero-unit">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Sample 2: Click to show datepicker" id="example2">
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example1').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        autoclose: true
    });

    //Alternativ way
    $('#example2').datepicker({
      format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    }).on('change', function(){
        $('.datepicker').hide();
    });

});
```

this is all you have to do :)

**[HERE IS A FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ma3rR/403/)** to see whats happening.

**Fiddleupdate on 13 of July 2016: CDN wasnt present anymore**

According to your EDIT:

```
$('#example1').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    $('#example1').Close();
});
```

Here you take the Input (that has no Close-Function) and create a Datepicker-Element. If the element changes you want to close it but you still try to close the Input (That has no close-function).

> Binding a mouseup event to the document state **may not** be the best idea because you will fire all containing scripts on each click!

Thats it :)

**EDIT: August 2017 (Added a StackOverFlowFiddle aka Snippet. Same as in Top of Post)**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example1').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        autoclose: true
    });

    //Alternativ way
    $('#example2').datepicker({
      format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    }).on('change', function(){
        $('.datepicker').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.hero-unit{
  float: left;
  width: 210px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
.hero-unit input{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="hero-unit">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Sample 1: Click to show datepicker" id="example1">
    </div>
    <div class="hero-unit">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Sample 2: Click to show datepicker" id="example2">
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT: December 2018 Obviously Bootstrap-Datepicker doesnt work with jQuery 3.x [see this to fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41236574/bootstrap-datetimepicker-not-working-with-the-jquery-3)**

Comment: if you want to hide only when a day is selected you can use

if (ev.viewMode == 'days') {
  $(this).datepicker('hide');
}

Comment: 'autoclose:true' nailed it.

Comment: It is [documented in Bootstrap](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#autoclose) but obviously also works in jQuery where its not really documented.

Comment: @Dwza how can we use your answer of datepicker in ionic 2 , can you please help us, we need to do this date picker in ionic 2 app, so please help us....then we have asked question also in stackoverflow  please look out this and help us :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610110/dynamic-datepicker-with-repeat-option-similar-to-alarm  .... thanks...

Comment: @R.ManiSelvam i know its a bit late and i really dont know about ionic as well but reading the documentation of it brings up some informations that might help. See https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker obviously there are 2 callback funtions that can be passen. On for success and one for error. There you could easily handle the behaviour of your datepicker. Actually im just guessing because i dont have any way to test it.

Comment: 'autoclose: true' not working, but I did it like this `$( '#date' ).datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        }).on( 'changeDate', function(){
            $( '.datepicker' ).hide();
        });`

Comment: @TroyanVictor what version do you use? `autoclose: true` was a valid way to close it. But as i see, my alternativ way still works :)

Comment: @Dwza version 2.0. thnx for the alternative way, this solution save my time :)

Comment: @TroyanVictor You mean jQuery 2.0 ?

Comment: @Dwza as it turned out, on the project is used bootstrap-datepicker. at the expense of the version, not there looked

Comment: see what's happening is when i select from date is going to be correct but after i select to date can be select any date this is not correct. this is may be help full
refer this link http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/M2RS8/

Comment: This is only if you restrict date isnt it?

Answer (score 8):

This is my edited version : you just need to add an extra argument "autoClose".

example :

```
 $('input[name="fieldName"]').datepicker({ autoClose: true});
```

also you can specify a close callback if you want. :)

replace datepicker.js with this:

```
!function( $ ) {

// Picker object

var Datepicker = function(element, options , closeCallBack){
    this.element = $(element);
    this.format = DPGlobal.parseFormat(options.format||this.element.data('date-format')||'dd/mm/yyyy');
    this.autoClose = options.autoClose||this.element.data('date-autoClose')|| true;
    this.closeCallback = closeCallBack || function(){};
    this.picker = $(DPGlobal.template)
                        .appendTo('body')
                        .on({
                            click: $.proxy(this.click, this)//,
                            //mousedown: $.proxy(this.mousedown, this)
                        });
    this.isInput = this.element.is('input');
    this.component = this.element.is('.date') ? this.element.find('.add-on') : false;

    if (this.isInput) {
        this.element.on({
            focus: $.proxy(this.show, this),
            //blur: $.proxy(this.hide, this),
            keyup: $.proxy(this.update, this)
        });
    } else {
        if (this.component){
            this.component.on('click', $.proxy(this.show, this));
        } else {
            this.element.on('click', $.proxy(this.show, this));
        }
    }

    this.minViewMode = options.minViewMode||this.element.data('date-minviewmode')||0;
    if (typeof this.minViewMode === 'string') {
        switch (this.minViewMode) {
            case 'months':
                this.minViewMode = 1;
                break;
            case 'years':
                this.minViewMode = 2;
                break;
            default:
                this.minViewMode = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    this.viewMode = options.viewMode||this.element.data('date-viewmode')||0;
    if (typeof this.viewMode === 'string') {
        switch (this.viewMode) {
            case 'months':
                this.viewMode = 1;
                break;
            case 'years':
                this.viewMode = 2;
                break;
            default:
                this.viewMode = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    this.startViewMode = this.viewMode;
    this.weekStart = options.weekStart||this.element.data('date-weekstart')||0;
    this.weekEnd = this.weekStart === 0 ? 6 : this.weekStart - 1;
    this.onRender = options.onRender;
    this.fillDow();
    this.fillMonths();
    this.update();
    this.showMode();
};

Datepicker.prototype = {
    constructor: Datepicker,

    show: function(e) {
        this.picker.show();
        this.height = this.component ? this.component.outerHeight() : this.element.outerHeight();
        this.place();
        $(window).on('resize', $.proxy(this.place, this));
        if (e ) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (!this.isInput) {
        }
        var that = this;
        $(document).on('mousedown', function(ev){
            if ($(ev.target).closest('.datepicker').length == 0) {
                that.hide();
            }
        });
        this.element.trigger({
            type: 'show',
            date: this.date
        });
    },

    hide: function(){
        this.picker.hide();
        $(window).off('resize', this.place);
        this.viewMode = this.startViewMode;
        this.showMode();
        if (!this.isInput) {
            $(document).off('mousedown', this.hide);
        }
        //this.set();
        this.element.trigger({
            type: 'hide',
            date: this.date
        });
    },

    set: function() {
        var formated = DPGlobal.formatDate(this.date, this.format);
        if (!this.isInput) {
            if (this.component){
                this.element.find('input').prop('value', formated);
            }
            this.element.data('date', formated);
        } else {
            this.element.prop('value', formated);
        }
    },

    setValue: function(newDate) {
        if (typeof newDate === 'string') {
            this.date = DPGlobal.parseDate(newDate, this.format);
        } else {
            this.date = new Date(newDate);
        }
        this.set();
        this.viewDate = new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth(), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        this.fill();
    },

    place: function(){
        var offset = this.component ? this.component.offset() : this.element.offset();
        this.picker.css({
            top: offset.top + this.height,
            left: offset.left
        });
    },

    update: function(newDate){
        this.date = DPGlobal.parseDate(
            typeof newDate === 'string' ? newDate : (this.isInput ? this.element.prop('value') : this.element.data('date')),
            this.format
        );
        this.viewDate = new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth(), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        this.fill();
    },

    fillDow: function(){
        var dowCnt = this.weekStart;
        var html = '<tr>';
        while (dowCnt < this.weekStart + 7) {
            html += '<th class="dow">'+DPGlobal.dates.daysMin[(dowCnt++)%7]+'</th>';
        }
        html += '</tr>';
        this.picker.find('.datepicker-days thead').append(html);
    },

    fillMonths: function(){
        var html = '';
        var i = 0
        while (i < 12) {
            html += '<span class="month">'+DPGlobal.dates.monthsShort[i++]+'</span>';
        }
        this.picker.find('.datepicker-months td').append(html);
    },

    fill: function() {
        var d = new Date(this.viewDate),
            year = d.getFullYear(),
            month = d.getMonth(),
            currentDate = this.date.valueOf();
        this.picker.find('.datepicker-days th:eq(1)')
                    .text(DPGlobal.dates.months[month]+' '+year);
        var prevMonth = new Date(year, month-1, 28,0,0,0,0),
            day = DPGlobal.getDaysInMonth(prevMonth.getFullYear(), prevMonth.getMonth());
        prevMonth.setDate(day);
        prevMonth.setDate(day - (prevMonth.getDay() - this.weekStart + 7)%7);
        var nextMonth = new Date(prevMonth);
        nextMonth.setDate(nextMonth.getDate() + 42);
        nextMonth = nextMonth.valueOf();
        var html = [];
        var clsName,
            prevY,
            prevM;
        while(prevMonth.valueOf() < nextMonth) {zs
            if (prevMonth.getDay() === this.weekStart) {
                html.push('<tr>');
            }
            clsName = this.onRender(prevMonth);
            prevY = prevMonth.getFullYear();
            prevM = prevMonth.getMonth();
            if ((prevM < month &&  prevY === year) ||  prevY < year) {
                clsName += ' old';
            } else if ((prevM > month && prevY === year) || prevY > year) {
                clsName += ' new';
            }
            if (prevMonth.valueOf() === currentDate) {
                clsName += ' active';
            }
            html.push('<td class="day '+clsName+'">'+prevMonth.getDate() + '</td>');
            if (prevMonth.getDay() === this.weekEnd) {
                html.push('</tr>');
            }
            prevMonth.setDate(prevMonth.getDate()+1);
        }
        this.picker.find('.datepicker-days tbody').empty().append(html.join(''));
        var currentYear = this.date.getFullYear();

        var months = this.picker.find('.datepicker-months')
                    .find('th:eq(1)')
                        .text(year)
                        .end()
                    .find('span').removeClass('active');
        if (currentYear === year) {
            months.eq(this.date.getMonth()).addClass('active');
        }

        html = '';
        year = parseInt(year/10, 10) * 10;
        var yearCont = this.picker.find('.datepicker-years')
                            .find('th:eq(1)')
                                .text(year + '-' + (year + 9))
                                .end()
                            .find('td');
        year -= 1;
        for (var i = -1; i < 11; i++) {
            html += '<span class="year'+(i === -1 || i === 10 ? ' old' : '')+(currentYear === year ? ' active' : '')+'">'+year+'</span>';
            year += 1;
        }
        yearCont.html(html);
    },

    click: function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(e.target).closest('span, td, th');
        if (target.length === 1) {
            switch(target[0].nodeName.toLowerCase()) {
                case 'th':
                    switch(target[0].className) {
                        case 'switch':
                            this.showMode(1);
                            break;
                        case 'prev':
                        case 'next':
                            this.viewDate['set'+DPGlobal.modes[this.viewMode].navFnc].call(
                                this.viewDate,
                                this.viewDate['get'+DPGlobal.modes[this.viewMode].navFnc].call(this.viewDate) + 
                                DPGlobal.modes[this.viewMode].navStep * (target[0].className === 'prev' ? -1 : 1)
                            );
                            this.fill();
                            this.set();
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'span':
                    if (target.is('.month')) {
                        var month = target.parent().find('span').index(target);
                        this.viewDate.setMonth(month);
                    } else {
                        var year = parseInt(target.text(), 10)||0;
                        this.viewDate.setFullYear(year);
                    }
                    if (this.viewMode !== 0) {
                        this.date = new Date(this.viewDate);
                        this.element.trigger({
                            type: 'changeDate',
                            date: this.date,
                            viewMode: DPGlobal.modes[this.viewMode].clsName
                        });
                    }
                    this.showMode(-1);
                    this.fill();
                    this.set();
                    break;
                case 'td':
                    if (target.is('.day') && !target.is('.disabled')){
                        var day = parseInt(target.text(), 10)||1;
                        var month = this.viewDate.getMonth();
                        if (target.is('.old')) {
                            month -= 1;
                        } else if (target.is('.new')) {
                            month += 1;
                        }
                        var year = this.viewDate.getFullYear();
                        this.date = new Date(year, month, day,0,0,0,0);
                        this.viewDate = new Date(year, month, Math.min(28, day),0,0,0,0);
                        this.fill();
                        this.set();
                        this.element.trigger({
                            type: 'changeDate',
                            date: this.date,
                            viewMode: DPGlobal.modes[this.viewMode].clsName
                        });
                        if(this.autoClose === true){
                            this.hide();
                            this.closeCallback();
                        }

                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    },

    mousedown: function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    },

    showMode: function(dir) {
        if (dir) {
            this.viewMode = Math.max(this.minViewMode, Math.min(2, this.viewMode + dir));
        }
        this.picker.find('>div').hide().filter('.datepicker-'+DPGlobal.modes[this.viewMode].clsName).show();
    }
};

$.fn.datepicker = function ( option, val ) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var datePicker = $this.data('datepicker');
        var options = typeof option === 'object' && option;
        if (!datePicker) {
            if (typeof val === 'function')
                $this.data('datepicker', (datePicker = new Datepicker(this, $.extend({}, $.fn.datepicker.defaults,options),val)));
            else{
                $this.data('datepicker', (datePicker = new Datepicker(this, $.extend({}, $.fn.datepicker.defaults,options))));
            }
        }
        if (typeof option === 'string') datePicker[option](val);

    });
};

$.fn.datepicker.defaults = {
    onRender: function(date) {
        return '';
    }
};
$.fn.datepicker.Constructor = Datepicker;

var DPGlobal = {
    modes: [
        {
            clsName: 'days',
            navFnc: 'Month',
            navStep: 1
        },
        {
            clsName: 'months',
            navFnc: 'FullYear',
            navStep: 1
        },
        {
            clsName: 'years',
            navFnc: 'FullYear',
            navStep: 10
    }],
    dates:{
        days: ["Dimanche", "Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi", "Dimanche"],
                    daysShort: ["Dim", "Lun", "Mar", "Mer", "Jeu", "Ven", "Sam", "Dim"],
                    daysMin: ["D", "L", "Ma", "Me", "J", "V", "S", "D"],
                    months: ["Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Août", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre"],
                    monthsShort: ["Jan", "Fév", "Mar", "Avr", "Mai", "Jui", "Jul", "Aou", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Déc"],
                    today: "Aujourd'hui",
                    clear: "Effacer",
                    weekStart: 1,
                    format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    },
    isLeapYear: function (year) {
        return (((year % 4 === 0) && (year % 100 !== 0)) || (year % 400 === 0))
    },
    getDaysInMonth: function (year, month) {
        return [31, (DPGlobal.isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28), 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][month]
    },
    parseFormat: function(format){
        var separator = format.match(/[.\/\-\s].*?/),
            parts = format.split(/\W+/);
        if (!separator || !parts || parts.length === 0){
            throw new Error("Invalid date format.");
        }
        return {separator: separator, parts: parts};
    },
    parseDate: function(date, format) {
        var parts = date.split(format.separator),
            date = new Date(),
            val;
        date.setHours(0);
        date.setMinutes(0);
        date.setSeconds(0);
        date.setMilliseconds(0);
        if (parts.length === format.parts.length) {
            var year = date.getFullYear(), day = date.getDate(), month = date.getMonth();
            for (var i=0, cnt = format.parts.length; i < cnt; i++) {
                val = parseInt(parts[i], 10)||1;
                switch(format.parts[i]) {
                    case 'dd':
                    case 'd':
                        day = val;
                        date.setDate(val);
                        break;
                    case 'mm':
                    case 'm':
                        month = val - 1;
                        date.setMonth(val - 1);
                        break;
                    case 'yy':
                        year = 2000 + val;
                        date.setFullYear(2000 + val);
                        break;
                    case 'yyyy':
                        year = val;
                        date.setFullYear(val);
                        break;
                }
            }
            date = new Date(year, month, day, 0 ,0 ,0);
        }
        return date;
    },
    formatDate: function(date, format){
        var val = {
            d: date.getDate(),
            m: date.getMonth() + 1,
            yy: date.getFullYear().toString().substring(2),
            yyyy: date.getFullYear()
        };
        val.dd = (val.d < 10 ? '0' : '') + val.d;
        val.mm = (val.m < 10 ? '0' : '') + val.m;
        var date = [];
        for (var i=0, cnt = format.parts.length; i < cnt; i++) {
            date.push(val[format.parts[i]]);
        }
        return date.join(format.separator);
    },
    headTemplate: '<thead>'+
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<th class="prev">&lsaquo;</th>'+
                            '<th colspan="5" class="switch"></th>'+
                            '<th class="next">&rsaquo;</th>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                    '</thead>',
    contTemplate: '<tbody><tr><td colspan="7"></td></tr></tbody>'
};
DPGlobal.template = '<div class="datepicker dropdown-menu">'+
                        '<div class="datepicker-days">'+
                            '<table class=" table-condensed">'+
                                DPGlobal.headTemplate+
                                '<tbody></tbody>'+
                            '</table>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div class="datepicker-months">'+
                            '<table class="table-condensed">'+
                                DPGlobal.headTemplate+
                                DPGlobal.contTemplate+
                            '</table>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div class="datepicker-years">'+
                            '<table class="table-condensed">'+
                                DPGlobal.headTemplate+
                                DPGlobal.contTemplate+
                            '</table>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>';

}( window.jQuery );
```

Answer (score 4):

There is another code that's works for me (jQuery).

```js
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    autoHide: true
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.css" />
Date: <input type="text" readonly="true" class="datepicker">
```

Comment: autohide: true - for me. No uppercase letters.

Answer (score 2):

Answer above did not work for me on Chrome. The change event was been fired after I clicked out of the field somewhere, which did not help because the datepicker window is also closed too when you click out of the field.

I did use this code and it worked pretty well. You can place it after calling `.datepicker();`

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker-input" placeholder="click to show datepicker" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".datepicker-input").each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker();
});

$(".datepicker-input").click(function() {
    $(".datepicker-days .day").click(function() {
        $('.datepicker').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this option to Datepicker component:

> forceParse: false

Example:

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    defaultDate: 'now',
    forceParse: false,
    endDate: "today"
  });
```