# Bootstrap-Datetimepicker not working with the jQuery 3

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker, jquery-3

Bootstrap-datetimepicker is not working with jQuery 3.1.1. I need to use the same jQuery library to run all the other dependent functions.

Comment: jQuery ***3.3.1***? :O :O

Comment: @philantrovert he's from the future :))

Comment: @Karan Batra please wait until jquery reaches v 3.3.1 and we will help you then :))

Comment: Please file your issue here: https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues

Comment: @KaranBatra Are you using moment.js?

Comment: yes, I am using moment.js.

Comment: what is bootstrap version u have been using

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the docs, the required files for bootstrap datetimepicker to run are :

> jQuery
>
> Moment.js
>
> Bootstrap.js
>
> Bootstrap CSS
>
> Bootstrap Datepicker CSS
>
> Locales: Moment's locale files

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oq9y2mw9/) and check **External Resources** on the left

Initialize like this

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
```

I have used the following files :
jQuery 3.1.1

[moment.js](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js)

[bootstrap.min.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css)

[bootstrap.min.js](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js)

[bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css)

[bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js)

Also, read this [installation](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/) post in the documentation for better understanding.

Comment: Issue resolved with above above mentioned files. Thanks

Comment: I am using same jQuery 3.1.1 but it does not working . My files order are :
jquery-3.1.1.js
moment.js
bootstrap.3.3.7.min.js
moment-with-locales.js
jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js
bootstrap-datetimepicker.js

Comment: @philantrovert thanks for getting back. It seems working fine. i was using `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js` rather then `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js` but it works with `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js`. 

I would like to update approved answer. The order is must only for `Javascript` files.  I have added CSS separately and everything is working fine for me. Once again thanks for your positive answer.

Comment: @Muhammad that's strange. A `min` is essentially a minified version of the same javascript file. Great that you got it worked out though.

Comment: `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js` is not compatible with `jquery.3.1.1` due to this exception: `jQuery.Deferred exception: input.size is not a function TypeError: input.size is not a function`

Comment: You need a more recent jQuery migrate.

Comment: @LudovicKuty Looks like your suggestion of updating jquery may have solved it. Kind of hidden here at the end and I didn't even see it until the fifth time reading through.

Answer (score 13):

I am getting same error.

```
input.size is not a function TypeError
```

modify **bootstrap-datetimepicker.js** line no: 2253

```
if (input.size() === {
```

to

```
if (input.length === 0) {
```

**line no:2264**

```
if (element.find('.datepickerbutton').size() === 0) {
```

to

```
if (element.find('.datepickerbutton').length === 0) {
```

add css

```
.input-group.date .dropdown-menu{
     display: block;    
 }
```

Comment: This worked until I updated Bootstrap. If they haven't fixed it yet, there must be some other workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.datepicker-manual').datepicker({
 startDate: new Date(),
 format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', //you can change date format to any
 autoclose: true,
 todayHighlight: true,
 placeholder:new Date(),
 startDate: new Date(), //this will be today's date
 endDate: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 360))
});
$(document).on( "change", ".datepicker-manual", function() {
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

Comment: 100% working for me... change event is import to auto hide...