# How to implement aria-expanded value in jQuery Datepicker?

Tags: jquery, accessibility, jquery-ui-datepicker, input-button-image

I am looking for implementation of aria expanded under .ui-datepicker-trigger , so when ever the focus or tab button is hit , if the calendar is expanded , the narrator should narrate calendar expanded , when focus is off it should say calendar collapsed.
The below is the code.

```
 $("#txtIssueDateTo").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', showOn: 'both', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: 'images/calender.png', maxDate: 'today', buttonText: "Select to date button"});

     $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            this.click();
            this.focus();
        }});
```

[img-1 Should narrate calendar collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGd6i.png)
[img-2 After hitting enter it should narrate calendar expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATEkt.png)

[An html+ javascript demo is here](http://www.davidmacd.com/blog/toggle-aria-expanded-javascript.html)

```
<button onclick="myFunction()"  id="p2" aria-expanded="false">Try it</button>
 <script>
  function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("p2").getAttribute("aria-expanded"); 
  if (x == "true") 
  {
  x = "false"
  } else {
  x = "true"
  }
  document.getElementById("p2").setAttribute("aria-expanded", x);
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: Can you also put the code in a fiddle like this one? http://jsfiddle.net/Uv8V4/  Is any of this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714217/focus-on-jquery-ui-calender-accessibility-with-tab-key  Searching for expanded doesn't seem to show anything helpful.  Is there another word for expanded?

Comment: Is any of this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040165/jquery-datepicker-close-datepicker-after-selected-date